# Bind kendo.data.datasource json data to kendo listview

Tags: json, listview, kendo-ui

Category1 works but category doesn't. Both have same data. But category is a json response. 
category is

```
{
    "d": [
        {"__type": "MenuData+Category", "id": 1, "name": "drinks"},
        {"__type": "MenuData+Category", "id": 2, "name": "fruits"}
    ]
}
```

Do I remove the `d`. If so how do i do it? If not whats wrong?

```
    <div id="categories" data-role="view" data-title="Categories">
        <header data-role="header">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <span data-role="view-title"></span>
            </div>
        </header>
        <ul id="Ul1"
            data-role="listview" 
            data-source="category" [NOTE: Changing this datasource to category1 works]
            data-template="categories-template" 
            data-style="inset">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script id="categories-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        #: name #
    </script>

    <script>  

        var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(),
        category = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:60143/Mobile/Menu/MenuData.asmx/getCategory",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("error " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "d"
                },
                type: "json",
                parameterMap: function (options) {
                    return JSON.stringify(options);
                }
            }
        }),
        category1 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: [
                { id: 1,name: "Fruits" },
                { id: 2,name: "Drinks" },
            ]
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have placed `schema` inside `transport` definition while it is member of `DataSource`.

Try:

```
category = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport      : {
        read: {
            type       : "POST",
            url        : "http://localhost:60143/Mobile/Menu/MenuData.asmx/getCategory",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType   : "json",
            error      : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("error " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    },
    schema         : {
        data: "d"
    },
    type           : "json",
    parameterMap   : function (options) {
        return JSON.stringify(options);
    }
});
```

Comment: You were right. That worked. But I have run into another problem. I cannot use filter method on the datasource. I changed this from odata to json. category.filter() worked on odata but doesnt work on json. Can you tell me why?

Comment: GET returns a 500 message: {"Message":"An attempt was made to call the method \u0027HelloWorld\u0027 using a GET request, which is not allowed.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

Comment: Just to let you know that i am using a different URL so the method name is different there. Also when I use category.filter({field: "id", operator: "eq", value: 1}) I get an error response saying {"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: skip.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize......

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a KendoUI question but a server side problem that is not able to parse the JSON received. You should post a new question on this and get more visibility to the question.